# Will unity 6.2 be available for ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: 12.04, unity

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it possible to install Unity 6.x.x on Ubuntu 12.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/197941/is-it-possible-to-install-unity-6-x-x-on-ubuntu-12-04)

I was wondering if Unity 6.2 will be available anytime soon for ubuntu 12.04?